# Regular Expression Delete Everything Before String

Tags: regex

I have a list of data I want to clean

```
abcd.efgh.igk.l.domain.com
abcd.efgh.igk.domain.net
abcd.efgh.domain.org
```

In each instance I want to keep     domain.com,domain.net or domain.org

I can't figure our the correct regex. I tried to do:

```
^.*\.com$|^.*\.net$|^.*\.org$
```

The above regex doesn't work. The data will be completely random can be any number of characters but then there will always be domain.com,domain.net etc. I want to use a regex such as the domain ends in ".com" and delete everything to the left IF there is a subdomain/period etc. I hope that makes sense as "domain" will be different in every line

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex:

```
$regex='(?P<domain>\\w+\\.org|\\.com|\\.net)$'
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
echo $matches['domain'];
```

This regex searches for anything ending with `.com` , `.org`, or `.net` and returns the prepended alphanumeric characters (`.` is not alpha-numeric)

You can read more about preg_match [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Hi, this regex works but it deletes domain.com. I want to keep domain.com but delete everything to the left of it so sasas.asa.sas.as.as.ad.sdsa.da.12121.dsadad.21ddasdas.domain.com would return domain.com only

Comment: Sorry to add but I am using find and replace and the regex is Perl. Its a program that I use. I tried (?P<domain>\\w+\\.org|\\.com|\\.net)$ but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched characters with `\1`

```
^.*\.([^.]*\.(?:com|net|org))$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/7)

**Perl code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
   $line =~ s/^.*\.([^.]*\.(?:com|net|org))$/$1/g;
    print $line;;
}

__DATA__
abcd.efgh.igk.l.domain.com
abcd.efgh.igk.domain.net
abcd.efgh.domain.org
sasas.asa.sas.as.as.ad.sdsa.da.12121.dsadad.21ddasdas.domain.com
domain.org
```

Output:

```
domain.com
domain.net
domain.org
domain.com
domain.org
```

Comment: I got an error saying it is expecting 3 trailing decimal points. The decimals before domain.com can be 0 or unlimited and also the text before domain.com can be numbers and letters or a combination. Its to delete all subdomains

Comment: That regular expression is the correct output however it doesn't work in my program and gives me an error saying it is expecting 3 trailing decimal points. Is it a Perl Regex?

Comment: Im not sure why it isnt working but the program says regex pattern "Perl"

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*\.(?=[^.\n]*\.[^\n.]*)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/9

or

```
^.*\\.(?=[^.\\n]*\\.[^\\n.]*)
```

Comment: Hi no sorry that doesn't seem to be doing anything. It isnt giving me an error though so this could work with some modifying

Comment: @AmerA you need to use perl's replace.Check demo.it does work.Did you try both the options?

Comment: So I got ^.*\.(?=[^.\n]*\.[^\n.]*) to work however if it is a domain such as .com.au then it will delete the .com also. How can I make it work for domains with ".com.au"

Comment: @AmerA it will be extremely difficult to use the same regex for that too.Instead filter such url before and apply a modified regex over it.

Comment: I have managed to filter those urls. Do you know the regex I would need for that?